# Django : Zipping selected object's pdf

Tags: python, django, zip

I have an Index view that displays Trainer name, location, etc as well s a button to download their Profile(already in database as a pdf). I search and filter these based on some parameters. Now i want to be able to select  a few of these and download the selected Trainer Profiles.Im new to Django and can't figure out how to do that. Here's my code. It says 'FieldFile object is not callable'
views.py
        def download(request):
    import zipfile
    import os

```
file = zipfile.ZipFile("C:\\Downloads\\test.zip", "w")

filelist = []
filelist+= 'Trainer.checkboxoption' in request.REQUEST
for i in filelist:
   file.write(i)

file.close()
return render(request,'trainer/index.html')
```

index.html

```
    <form action="download/" method="post">
            <div class="caption">
                <div >
                    <table style="width:100%" class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Technology</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th> View</th>
                            <th>Download</th>
                            <th>Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                        {% for trainer in all_trainers %}
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="trainer{{ forloop.counter }}" name="trainer" value="{{ trainer.id }}"></td>
                                <td> <a href="/trainer/{{ trainer.id }}">{{ trainer.name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ trainer.technology }}</td></a>
                                <td>{{ trainer.location }}</td>
                                <!-- View Details -->
                                <td><a href="/trainer/{{ trainer.id }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">View Details</a></td>

                                <td><a href="../media/{{ trainer.trainer_profile }}" class="btn">Download PDF</a></td>

                                <!-- Delete Album -->
                                <td><form action="trainer/{{trainer.id }}/delete/" method="post">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    <input type="hidden" name="trainer_id" value="{{ trainer.id }}" />
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </form></td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Download ZIP">
        </form>
```

Comment: Why does it need to be in a zip?

Comment: It would be difficult to download each of them seperately.. there are over 1000s of files

Comment: Ah ok, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

views.py:

```
    def download(request):
        import zipfile
        filef = zipfile.ZipFile("test.zip", "w")
        var = request.POST.getlist('checks')
        pdfprofile = []
        for i in var:
            trainer= Trainer.objects.get(pk=i)
            pdfprofile.append(trainer.trainer_profile)

        for i in pdfprofile:
            filef.write("D:\\Django\\myproduct\\media\\"+str(i))
        filef.close()

        response = HttpResponse(open("test.zip", "rb").read(), content_type='application/zip')
         response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=test.zip'
        return response
```